# Consejo para ocultar código php cuando hago una redirección

Tags: php, javascript

En mi página web tengo un servicio de mensajería el cual, una vez se de al botón "enviar", se redirige a un fichero php llamado "contacto.php".

Éste a su vez, cuando valida que están disponibles todas las variables, envía la información, crea un mensaje de alerta avisando al usuario de que se ha enviado el correo, y luego redirige a la página anterior de nuevo.
tal que así: 
(El código php lo resumo en un comentario, pues es irrelevante)

**Código php**

```
<?php
    //Variables y funciones varias para el envío de información por correo, una vez terminadas, redirige a la web principal:
     echo "<script>
            alert('Gracias por ponerte en contacto con nosotros.');
            window.location= '../index.html';
     </script>";
?>
```

El problema que he encontrado, es que cuando hace esta redirección al index.html, se muestra el código php anterior en el navegador durante 1 segundo...
¿Cómo podría hacer para que la redirección fuera inmediata? o al menos, ¿no se mostrara dicho código?

Comment: @Shaz el único problema que me estoy encontrando está ahí, en el método de redirección, el resto es código html o php irrelevante, ya que es muy básico o no aporta nada más que líneas a este post. Intentaré modificarlo un poco.

Comment: Puedes utilizar header para hacer la redirección directamente desde php sin tener que utilizar ningún print/echo

Comment: ¿En serio estás ejecutando código PHP desde un archivo HTML? ¿Abriste un posible agujero de seguridad en tu servidor para ello? ¿Por qué no usas Ajax? De ese modo podrías delegar todo el trabajo que deba hacerse en el servidor a tu archivo PHP, recuperar la respuesta de ese archivo y usarla de nuevo en el HTML de una forma totalmente transparente.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo siento, mis conocimientos son limitados, soy novato en esto. He echado un vistazo rapido a AJAX, y lo que permite es de manera sincronizada, comunicar el php con el html, sin que haga falta redirecciones ni actualizaciones de datos. ¿Me equivoco?.

Comment: Se muestra qué código PHP en el navegador?

Comment: Pelayo no es exactamente eso. Ciertamente si usas Ajax las redirecciones no son estrictamente necesarias (aunque puedes hacerlas si así lo quisieras). En cambio, actualizaciones sí hay. En teoría lo que hace Ajax es: 1. Desde el archivo actual (HTML en este caso) enviar cualquier dato al servidor; 2. Recibir una respuesta del resultado de ese envío, que puede ser un estatus, pueden ser datos obtenidos en la base de datos, etc; 3. En base a esa respuesta, actualizar el archivo actual (HTML en este caso)  o redirigir a otra parte si fuera necesario. Una de las ventajas de Ajax es que ...

Comment: ... puedes enviar y recibir datos del servidor sin tener que refrescar la página o redirigir. O sea, puedes cambiar el estado de la página de forma dinámica y transparente, sin moverte de ella. [Observa este ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/6fju-td04), en el cual, desde la página actual se manda a buscar datos según un `id` escrito en un campo de texto. La llamada a Ajax trae los datos desde el servidor y luego, sin moverte de la página, llenas el formulario con los datos que se han obtenido en el servidor. Como eso, cualquier otra acción es posible.